# Does the compressor stationary vane have stagger angle?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, compressor, blade

Does the compressor stationary vane have stagger angle? ( stagger angle is the angle between chord of the blade or vane with engine's longitudinal axis )

Answer (score 3):

The stationary compressors are responsible for guide the air particles flow to the next compressor or stage with an even air flow on the engine's longitudinal axis, taking under consideration angle adjustments in order to avoid air turbulence with may cause a compressor stall.

So, depending of the engine project, the answer is yes. The angle can variate, being static or even with self-adjustment.

Comment: Can you provide a source for an engine with self adjusting stator vanes? This is highly dubious. The stator vanes convert the velocity generated by the rotating blades, into pressure, as well as diverting the flow into the next stage of rotating blades. If they were aerodynamically self adjusting, the would not do these two functions as well, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Completely! But there are not aerodynamically adjusted stator vanes. They are just adjusted if the air flow is not even enough in order to avoid a high compressor stall. Unfortunately I don't have any image source open to public. My best regards,

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_J79

Comment: Ok, we are saying the same thing! Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Or, it can be variable. One of the great advances made with the [GE J79](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_J79) was a variable angle stationary vane setup.